# reinitialize component or an equivalent

Tags: angular

I have 2 components, one that logs a user in and another that is a navbar which changes based on the user being logged in or not.

If I log a user in or out, and then manually refresh the page, I get correct html from the navbar component, but if I e.g. just login and then am redirected via angular, I do not see the changes.

How can I achieve the same effect with angular redirection that is achieved when manually refreshing a page?

**navbar component**

```
userLoggedIn: boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
            this.userLoggedIn = true;
            this.user = localStorage.getItem("user").replace(/\"/g, "");
        } 

    }
```

**login component**

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res));
this.router.navigateByUrl('');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a gettter in your navigation component and not in ngOnInit

```
user:any;
get userLoggedIn()
{
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
         this.user = localStorage.getItem("user").replace(/\"/g, "");
         return true;
    } 
    return false;
 }
 ngOnInit() {
     //empty
 }
```

The "magic" is that "get" is executed after a change ocurred in your application if your navigationComponent.html use "userLoggedIn", e.g. in a < p *ngIf="userLoggedIn">user logged< /p>

Comment: This is great, I just have a slight problem, when logging out, which is in another component, I remove localStorage variable and redirect again, and it works but I get the following in the console, any idea how to remedy this? `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.`

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways would be to create shared service like `LoginService` that could hold state of the user. Service should be injected in both components. This service should expose field like `loggedIn` that is of type `Subject`. On login event, you should `emit` value from that `Subject`. Navbar component should `subscribe` to `loggedIn` state and act accordingly to value that is received.

Angular is heavily based on functional-reactive programming paradigm. Decoupled composition of components that is achieved by using Subjects and Observables is the key to understand Angular philosohpy. If you have further questions, please let me know.