# How to update parent nav bar after login successfully in child component in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have implemented a loginpage in Angular4.In parent app.component file I have created a nav bar with ligin and signup buttons.I have created a component for login and after login successfully,login,signup buttons should be hide and username should be apppear.For this one I have used localstorage for verifying userdata to hide the buttons.Iam pushing the login data into local storage in success block.But my problem is after login I am navigating again to parent html but there buttons are not hidding and name is not displaying.After refreshing ,it works well.How can I update the nav bar after navigating to it again in Angular4?
Below is my code:

```js
login component:
  this.storage.store('loginInfo',this.loginData);
  app component:
   this.uname = this.storage.retrieve('loginInfo');
```

```html
app.component:
<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+1234 567 892</li>
                    <li *ngIf="uname==undefined||uname==null"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></i><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li *ngIf="uname==undefined||uname==null"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></i><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-transform:none">Hi,<span style="color:red;font-size:18px"> {{ uname.user_display_name}}</span></a>
```

Comment: What I would recommend is making the login screen and the main screen a different component and html. Use a route to reroute to the correct component. Otherwise if want to use child views or different routes you will need alot of code to fix it every time.

Comment: You can use a gettter in your navigation component and not in ngOnInit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501434/reinitialize-component-or-an-equivalent/46502329#46502329

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that stores the state of the navigation bar

Then, update that service from the child component. The updated changes will travel to the shared service, and then to the parent component

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service